# Gradle ругается при добавлении SQlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gradle

Для работы с `SQlite` через `ORM` я добавил в `Gradle app` последнюю строчку:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
}
```

Но при компиляции теперь ругается:

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Заменить `compile` на `implementation`

Comment: тогда не компилируется из-за строчки:     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: при запуске пишет:   Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$4
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$4, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

а в Gradle подчеркивает строчку implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: `'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5` попробуй

Comment: да, с 1.5 все заработало, спасибо